# Match A JSON Field In Get_Where Query (Code Igniter)

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

I am doing a result_array() in my get_where query but the column in 'added_by' is json format to {'id': '(the id)'}

How Can I do a get_where query to match the current users id.

Heres what I have so far.

```
$this->db
     ->order_by('till', 'desc')
     ->get_where('coupon', 
          [
               'added_by' => json_encode(array('id'=> $this->session->user_id)), 
               'status' => 'ok'
          ]
     )
     ->result_array()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json_encode` will return `{"id": $id}`. If you are OK with `{"id": "$id"}`, then you just need to force coerce to string:

```
json_encode(array('id'=> $this->session->user_id . ''))
```

If you need `{'id': '$id'}`, you will need to do a string replace manually.

```
str_replace( '"', '\'', json_encode(array('id'=> $this->session->user_id . ''))
```

Comment: This only works if in the db its {'type': and 'id'} all single ' ... I need it to work with double quotes like {"type": "id"

Comment: @Gilbert If it needs to be double, then use the first example :-)